# What does "Final Fantasy" mean in-universe in "Final Fantasy: Spirits Within"?

Tags: final-fantasy

We know that out of universe, "**Final Fantasy**" simply refers to the brand/franchise.

But what does it mean **in-universe** in the "*Final Fantasy: Spirits Within*" film?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy#Origin

Comment: @Richard - that section doesn't mention the film at all. And is out of universe.

Comment: ... absolutely nothing? (yes, snarking, but honestly can't think of a thing)

Comment: @Radhil - I'd prefer WoG confirmation even for an empty set.

Comment: What exactly do you expect? The name is from the original Final Fantasy video game. The origin of the name is explained in Richard's link. The movie is named Final Fantasy as a weak tie-in with the video game franchise. It has no in-universe meaning in any of the games or movies, because it has nothing to do with them other than the developer's feelings when making the first game and branding. There isn't WoG for everything, and I'm guessing this is one of those things nobody has bothered explicitly stating because they expected people could figure it out well enough on their own.

Comment: @MikeKellogg - well, one thing i do NOT expect is rude comments.

Comment: I'm sorry if you find it rude when I'm simply repeating what's said in the link and pointing out what I felt should be the obvious conclusion from it. You're looking for a WoG statement that is highly unlikely to exist, and I'm just explaining why that is. I also don't see what about that comment could be construed as "rude," so as a favor to someone with Asperger's, maybe you could explain that?

Answer (score 3):

*Just going to throw this idea out there (rather comment this but unfortunately it's too long).*

From the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), the term ['fantasy'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fantasy) is defined as:

> *The faculty or activity of imagining impossible or improbable things.*

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_The_Spirits_Within), the first line of the plot reads:

```
In 2065, Earth is infested by alien life forms known as Phantoms.
```

If we were to combine these two pieces of information and start claiming to people that in 50 years time from now, Earth will be overrun by aliens - they're gonna think you're nuts! Simply because the chances of it happening are fairly slim so to them it would be a fantasy.

Now fast forward to 2065 and fantasy has become reality. But as our heroes save the day, it is the ['end'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/end) (which can be a synonym of 'final') of the whole event. Most people would probably still need to come to terms as to what happened as less than a year before, the idea of an alien infestation would still have been a fantasy.

So for me and my weird brain, this would be where the term **Final Fantasy** would come from - **an end to an improbable event.**